terraform shell script execution parse to variable
I am trying to create a terraform code to run shell script and that output i like parse into variable on runtime to Parse in locals.
expected:
Output of null_resource block generates map value, I like to Input in aws_s3_bucket resource block
Note:
1)I can generate map format using shell script, I like to input in local variable or any medium


resource "null_resource" "execute_shell_script" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command     = "bash ${path.module}/shell_3.sh"
    interpreter = ["bash", "-c"]
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "buckets" {
  for_each = var.instance_config

  bucket = each.key
  acl    = "private"
}



#!/bin/bash

echo "instance_config = {"

cluster="cluster1 cluster2"
cluster1_con="con1 con2 con3"
cluster2_con="con4 con5 con6"

for i in $cluster; do
    echo "    \"$i\" = ["
    con_var="${i}_con"
    con_values="${!con_var}"
    for node in $con_values; do
        echo "        \"$node\","
    done
    echo "    ]"
done

echo "}"

Shell script output
instance_config = {
    "cluster1" = [
        "con1",
        "con2",
        "con3"
    ]
    "cluster2" = [
        "con4",
        "con5",
        "con6"
    ]
}


So you want to create a JSON file?

It is indeed unclear what the intent is here, but it sounds as if you want: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/external, but also there may be something much simpler depending upon your true objective.

when running external datasource, my shell script fails while execution, Updated description

It's unclear how the output would be used for the buckets?
